# Why is Z3 "rounding" small reals to 1.0/0.0?

Tags: python, floating-point, z3, z3py, real-datatype

I'm using Z3's python API to do some linear real arithmetic. I have encountered a situation where reals very close to zero are somehow converted to 1.0/0.0. This in turn causes a floating point exception inside the C++ part of Z3.

For instance I have the following Python program:

```
from z3 import *
s = Solver()
s.add(0.00001 * Real("a") + 0.00001 * Real("b") > 0.0)
print(s.to_smt2())
result = s.check()
print(result)
print(s.model())
```

which produces the following output:

```
; benchmark generated from python API
(set-info :status unknown)
(declare-fun b () Real)
(declare-fun a () Real)
(assert
 (let ((?x10 (+ (* (/ 1.0 0.0) a) (* (/ 1.0 0.0) b))))
 (> ?x10 0.0)))
(check-sat)

Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

If I instead replace line 3 with

```
#s.add(Q(1,100000) * Real("a") + Q(1, 100000) * Real("b") > 0.0)
```

I get my expected output.

Does anyone have an explanation and a way how I can get this to work by using the normal Python floats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as it turns out, Z3 does not take the float as is, but instead converts it into a string and then tries to parse that string. For small numbers Pythons str() defaults to scientific notation, which can apparently not be properly parsed by Z3. Using `"{:.20f}".format(my_small_float)` or similar explicit conversions solved my problem.

Comment: I'd recommend sticking to the `Q(x, y)` notation, which'll bypass all the floating point conversion issues when dealing with reals.

Comment: Generally I'd agree, but in my actual application the floats come from a CSV file and are not hard-coded.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot replicate this. When I run your program, I get:

```
; benchmark generated from python API
(set-info :status unknown)
(declare-fun b () Real)
(declare-fun a () Real)
(assert
 (let ((?x10 (+ (* (/ 1.0 100000.0) a) (* (/ 1.0 100000.0) b))))
 (> ?x10 0.0)))
(check-sat)

sat
[b = 50000, a = 0]
```

which does not have the `(/ 1.0 0)` term you're talking about.

What version of z3 are you using? Perhaps you've got an old version that had a bug which got fixed? I'm on 4.8.13 (from GitHub master), though you can also go with the latest official release of 4.8.12.

**NB** Having said that, I think your "workaround" of using `Q(1, 100000)` is actually quite preferable, since it'll avoid all sorts of floating-point precision problems. Unless you're solving a floating-point logic problem, you should really never use float conversions this way, as there'll be gotchas about representation issues.

Comment: I am using Z3-solver 4.8.12 installed through pip with Python 3.10. Found a solution though.