# Incorrect result from python z3-solver on MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, z3, z3py

I am new on z3. I am trying to run the following python examples with z3.

```
from z3 import *

x = Real('x')
y = Real('y')
s = Solver()
s.add(And(x+y>1,x==0.00001,y==0.1))
print(s.check())
```

The returned result is `sat`, which I think is incorrect as x+y=0.10001<1. I also print out the solver s

```
[And(x + y > 1, x == 1/0, y == 1/10)]
```

which I notice have term x==1/0 with a 0 in the denominator. I am using Python 3.9.8, z3-solver 4.8.12.0 running on macOS 10.14.6 Mojave.

I also tried the exact same example on a machine with Ubuntu 20.04, python3.8, and z3-solver 4.8.10.0. The returned result is `unsat` and there is no 0 in the denominators when the solver is printed out.

Does anyone know if I am doing anything wrong here? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot replicate this with z3 4.8.14; where it prints `unsat`, like you found with 4.8.10. You should simply upgrade your version of z3.

There has been previous questions regarding this, and it appears in certain incarnations small numbers like `0.00001` weren't being correctly translated. I suspect you're suffering from the same. See here: [Why is Z3 "rounding" small reals to 1.0/0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69678274/why-is-z3-rounding-small-reals-to-1-0-0-0/69679391#69679391)

Upgrading would be the best; if you can't try the recommendation there: Instead of using `0.00001`, try `Q(1, 100000)` instead.

Comment: Hi alias, thank you very much for the help. I am able to solve the problem by updating my z3 version.